# fitting triple exponential term function to data

Tags: exponential-function, linear-regression, exponential-sum

The function, I am trying to fit to data is:
$$y(x) = −(A+B)e^{−x/a_1} + e^{−x/a_2} + Be^{−x/a_3}$$

this function is a little bit different to [Is it possible to find initial parameters when fitting triple exponential term function to data?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386040/is-it-possible-to-find-initial-parameters-when-fitting-triple-exponential-term-f/3141958),

Here, we have $5$ parameters. In the post by JJacquelin he mentioned he prepared a "Triple exponential.docx". Does anyone know where I can find this document?
And how can I get these paremeters?

Thanks.

Below is one example of data:

[experiment data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqsxS.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqsxS.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqsxS.jpg [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqsxS.jpg)

x   y

0   1662

1   1661

2   1662

3   1660

4   1660

5   1662

6   1662

7   1662

8   1661

9   1660

10  1660

11  1661

12  1663

13  1663

14  1661

15  1660

16  1661

17  1663

18  1661

19  1660

20  1661

21  1661

22  1663

23  1662

24  1660

25  1661

26  1662

27  1662

28  1664

29  1659

30  1660

31  1659

32  1663

33  1662

34  1662

35  1661

36  1660

37  1662

38  1664

39  1661

40  1662

41  1660

42  1662

43  1663

44  1664

45  1662

46  1661

47  1661

48  1662

49  1665

50  1662

51  1660

52  1662

53  1662

54  1664

55  1661

56  1662

57  1663

58  1671

59  1681

60  1688

61  1695

62  1700

63  1706

64  1709

65  1714

66  1717

67  1720

68  1724

69  1726

70  1728

71  1727

72  1727

73  1730

74  1730

75  1731

76  1728

77  1728

78  1726

79  1728

80  1728

81  1724

82  1722

83  1720

84  1722

85  1722

86  1720

87  1717

88  1713

89  1714

90  1712

91  1713

92  1708

93  1709

94  1709

95  1706

96  1706

97  1703

98  1702

99  1699

100 1699

101 1699

102 1697

103 1696

104 1694

105 1693

106 1694

107 1693

108 1692

109 1690

110 1689

111 1689

112 1689

113 1686

114 1686

115 1684

116 1686

117 1686

118 1682

119 1679

120 1680

121 1682

122 1682

123 1680

124 1678

125 1679

126 1679

127 1680

128 1681

129 1677

130 1675

131 1676

132 1676

133 1677

134 1676

135 1674

136 1673

137 1675

138 1676

139 1673

140 1672

141 1671

142 1675

143 1673

144 1673

145 1670

146 1670

147 1673

148 1673

149 1671

150 1670

151 1669

152 1670

153 1671

154 1671

155 1669

156 1669

157 1670

158 1671

159 1671

160 1669

161 1666

162 1668

163 1669

164 1668

165 1668

166 1668

167 1668

168 1669

169 1670

170 1670

171 1667

172 1666

173 1668

174 1670

175 1667

176 1667

177 1666

178 1666

179 1667

180 1667

181 1667

182 1665

183 1665

184 1667

185 1667

186 1665

187 1665

188 1666

189 1666

190 1667

191 1667

192 1663

193 1665

194 1666

195 1667

196 1665

197 1665

198 1664

199 1664

200 1666

201 1665

202 1664

203 1663

204 1665

205 1665

206 1666

207 1665

208 1663

209 1663

210 1664

211 1665

212 1665

213 1664

214 1663

215 1664

216 1666

217 1666

218 1665

219 1663

220 1664

221 1667

222 1666

223 1664

224 1664

225 1663

226 1665

227 1665

228 1665

229 1663

230 1665

231 1665

232 1665

233 1663

234 1663

235 1661

236 1662

237 1664

238 1665

239 1663

240 1662

241 1664

242 1666

243 1663

244 1662

245 1664

246 1662

247 1665

Comment: How to contact @JJacquelin

Comment: If @JJacquelin is here, could you send me your document to my email 194586@qq.com?

Comment: I sent it just now by e-mail. Just tell me if you got it. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Claude.

Comment: The parameters of this system
are known to be very sensitive
to the accuracy of the data.
How accurate are the values of the data points?

Comment: @g.kov I put one data

Comment: This triple exponential model suggests that 
a starting point is (0,0),
so before fitting you need to cut it 
(say, at about point 57) and shift to the origin.
Also, it's advisable to scale $x,y$
to fit the range $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Comment: @g.kov Thanks g.kov. Can you expain "scale x, y to fit the range (0,1)×(0,1)"? Does it mean take the range of x and y from 0 to 1?

Comment: Yes, just transform the range of 
$x\in[x_\min,x_\max]$ to $x'\in[0,1]$ 
and 
$y\in[y_\min,y_\max]$ to $y'\in[0,1]$.
But, as I mentioned, first you need to cut 
the junk data from the left.

Comment: Is there any real-world meaning of parameters $a_1,a_2,a_3,A,B$ ?

Comment: @ g.kov Actually, the data is the signal from scintillator, where a1 gives the time constant of the rise, and a2,a3 give the time constants of the fast and the slow decay components. A and B are the amplitute of fast and slow components. The signal starting point can be assigned to 0 at x=57.
If I transform the range of x to 0 to 1 then there is no meaning of time constants.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici. Hi ! Claude. Thanks you for sending the document to Fang Yongde . Cheers.

Comment: @Fang Yongde . My comments about the equation that you consider are included in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my late answer.

The function you are trying to fit to data :
$$y(x) = −(A+B)e^{−x/a_1} + e^{−x/a_2} + Be^{−x/a_3} \tag 1$$

is far to be convenient. Your data states $y(0)=1662$ while the above equation gives $y(0)=0$.

Obviously a constant is missing. One can suppose that the function might be :
$$y(x) =C −(A+B)e^{−x/a_1} + e^{−x/a_2} + Be^{−x/a_3}\tag 2$$

The regression involves six parameters. This is not an easy problem. Nevertheless, this can be carried out thanks to the method explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . In fact the case of equation on the form $(2)$ is not treated in the paper. But it is possible to extend the case treated pp.71-72 in the paper to the case of equation $(2)$.

I updated my software for equation $(2)$ and tested it with your data. The analysis of the result convinced me that the equation $(2)$, even much better than $(1)$, is still far to be convenient.

Of course a sum of exponential terms must be used, but on a different manner to combine them. The function $(3)$ allows a much better fitting :
$$y(x)=a+\frac{1}{b\:e^{\:p\:x}+c\:e^{\:q\:x}} \tag 3$$
The equation involves five parameters $p,q,a,b,c$. In case of data such as given by the OP one must have $p>0$ and $q<0$.

Unfortunately this kind of function is not theoretically studied and not applied in the paper referenced above. As a consequence one cannot take profit of the easy approach developed in the paper. The usual non-linear methods of regression are not easy with so many parameters especially for guessing  the initial values to start an iterative process.

The result below  was obtained with a non-linear regression method. The approximate values of the parameters are :
$$\begin{cases}
p\simeq 0.02670\\
q\simeq -0.27125\\
a\simeq 1661.6486\\
b\simeq 0.0018619\\
c\simeq 419482.7
\end{cases}$$
The root mean square error is 
$\quad\text{RMSE }\simeq 2.123\quad$ which is beautifully small compared to the order of magnitude (about $1700.$ ) of $y$ .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By chance, I had this document.

As a very quick answer, I should try @JJacquelin's method just to get an idea about parameters $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

I should keep them fixed at these values and perform the linear regression
$$y(x) =  A\left(e^{−x/a_2}-e^{−x/a_1}\right) + B\left(e^{−x/a_3}-e^{−x/a_1}\right)$$ to get $(A,B)$.

Now, use all of that for a nonlinear regression.

Please, let me know if it works.